# Python/Poetry - Avoid copying the codebase twice into dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize the application that I found here...

https://github.com/mmz-001/knowledge_gpt

The following script is working as expected. But I do not want to copy the code twice. How do I fine-tune this dockerfile?

```
# cat Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10
RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir /app/knowledge_gpt/
COPY * /app/knowledge_gpt/
COPY * /app/
WORKDIR /app/
ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}
RUN pip3 install poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install --no-dev
WORKDIR /app/knowledge_gpt/
CMD ["streamlit", "run", "main.py"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is within the `pyproject.toml`.
It has the following dependency:

```py
[tool.poetry]
name = "knowledge-gpt"
version = "0.1.0"

...

packages = [{include = "knowledge_gpt"}]
```

So cmd `poetry install` will try and build from the root of the project instead of building from the packages defined. Thus you will need to define the `--no-root` option to your build.

By copying it twice, poetry has built from the root of the project `/app`

Update the `Dockerfile` to the following:

```golang
FROM python:3.10
RUN mkdir /app
COPY * /app/
WORKDIR /app/
ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}
RUN pip3 install poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install --only main --no-root
CMD ["streamlit", "run", "main.py"]
```

I also created a docker-compose.yml to make building it easier:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  kgpt:
    image: knowledge-gpt
    container_name: knowledge-gpt
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8501:8501
    networks:
      default:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess

change this

```
COPY * /app/knowledge_gpt/
COPY * /app/
WORKDIR /app/
```

to this

```
COPY * /app/knowledge_gpt/
WORKDIR /app/knowledge_gpt/
```

This will copy the content and set the working directory to current

Comment: If I do that, I get an error:  /app/knowledge_gpt/knowledge_gpt does not contain any element

Comment: `/app/knowledge_gpt/knowledge_gpt `  from where this comes from? Two `knowledge_gpt` ?

Comment: If you try it, you will get the same (or similar) error.